# Optimization problem: x% of time, y% of resources, is it an improvement?

Tags: optimization, parametric, percentages

Preliminary: No, this isn't homework. This is how-do-I-present-my-results-accurately. It slightly crosses over into CS but the fundamental question is math - I'm just not sure how to phrase it without the CS-based word-problem.

Say there is some task `T` which requires `x` time and `y` memory to complete once. There is a variant of this task, `T'`, which requires `x'` time and `y'` memory to complete once.

Take "efficiency" to be defined as a measure of how many times the task can be run in a given amount of time.

Limited to `y` memory, if `x' = 0.5x` and `y' = 1y`, `T'` can be completed twice in `x` time by simply running it twice in series. Thus, `T'` is twice as efficient as `T` in this case.

Assuming sufficient memory, if `y' = 0.5y` and `x' = 1x`, `T'` can be completed twice in `x` time by running it twice in parallel. Thus, `T'` is also twice as efficient as `T` in this case.

If `x' = 0.5x` and `y' = 2y`, or vice versa, `T'` is equally efficient to `T`. Runs in half the time and twice the space, or twice the space in half the time.

My question: There must be some formula here, but I can't seem to figure out how I'm figuring it out in the simple cases (in a way extensible to automation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Barely posted this, and the answer comes to me. Looking at the changes as a decimal: Multiply them.